# Find $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\dotsb+\frac{1}{4n-1}+\frac{1}{4n}\right)^5.$

Tags: limits

> Find
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\dotsb+\frac{1}{4n-1}+\frac{1}{4n}\right)^5.$$

I don't know how to calculate this limit. Please show me the how to solve this limit.

Comment: The harmonic series grows llike $\ln n$ and even taken to the 5th power, this loses against the $n$ in the denominator. Hence the limit is 0$.

Comment: Please verify that the edit is correct. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thx for your motivation I just solved it. Thank you!

Comment: @cncritic : what was the solution?

Comment: @Arjang Right part of the equation(sum of 1/n) is less than 1+log4n and use compare test. You may need L'Hôpital's rule